# Using a fetch() function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to read a local .txt file, and assign the content to some variables.

Now I have tried:

```
  // Empty array to store the string from the text file
  var importedText = [];

  // Fetching .txt file
  fetch('text.txt')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then(data => importedText = data.split(/\r?\n/)); // import the string, separated by '\n'

  var t1 = importedText[0]; // these two returns undefined
  var t2 = importedText[1];
```

It appears that the variable `t1` and `t2` return undefined, even though both `importedText[0]` and `importedText[1]` return the desired string. Also, the array `importedText` seems to be perfectly fine (array containing the strings read from the text file).

I suspected that the fetch() function does not work that way that we can easily access the `importedText` inside it.

Can anyone help me with it? Thank you in advance.

Best,
GH

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous. > Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Oh. I cannot use fetch then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why can't you? Just move your code that accesses the value into the callback from your `fetch`.

Comment: @GenisiusHartanto Did you actually look at the link that explains why and how to work around it?